# Java Sockets - Sending File Then Reading Line Not Working

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send a list of strings from the server to a client, accompanied by files. Everything worked fine until I implemented the files. Now what happens is the file is sent, saves on my computer, then `line = in.readLine()` returns `null', resulting in '!line.equals("DONE")` throwing an error. The even stranger thing is is my curent code works on some computers and not others.

Server Code:

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
//Send all map data
System.out.println("Connected");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
File folder = new File("serverAssets" + File.separator + "dependencies");
File[] listFiles = folder.listFiles();
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
    File file = listFiles[i];
    out.println("file" + " " + file.getName() + " " + Long.toString(file.length()));
    String response = in.readLine();
    if (response.equals("READY")) {
        int count;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
        while ((count = bufferedIn.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        os.flush();
        bufferedIn.close();
    }
}
for (String line : main.mapData) {
    if (line != null || line != "") {
        out.println(line);  
    }
}
out.println("DONE");
socket.close();
```

Client Code:

```
String line = in.readLine();
while (!line.equals("DONE")) {
    String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
    if (splitLine[0].equals("object")) {
        ...deals with all the different lines of text
    }  else if (splitLine[0].equals("file")) {
        String name = splitLine[1];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.valueOf(splitLine[2])];
        out.println("READY");
        out.flush();

        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream b = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
        int count;
        int total = 0;
        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0 && total < bytes.length) {
            System.out.println(count);
            total += count;
            b.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        b.flush();
        b.close();
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
        Main.images.put(name, img);
    }
    line = in.readLine(); //returns null
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at xyz.krypticcoding.GuaranteeClient.run(GuaranteeClient.java:42)
        at xyz.krypticcoding.Main.connect(Main.java:1102)
        at xyz.krypticcoding.Main$6.actionPerformed(Main.java:934)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have a feeling it is to do with switching between the stream and `BufferedReader` but I am not sure.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and more details on how to reproduce the issue. Also, provide more details on the actual problem. If you are getting an error, always show the full error message with its Stacktrace.

Comment: `in.readLine()` can return null, so you need to check on the null...[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: @ecle I think the problem is that it reaches the end of the file stream, and the `in.readLine()` tries to read from that, as opposed to the text that is coming in afterwards. Just not sure how to rectify the issue.

Comment: @MichaelDuffett First, you still need to check for null on the `line` variable in `String line = in.readLine(); while (!line.equals("DONE"))`

Comment: @ecle The `null` comes from the second last line, the `line = in.readLine()`.

Comment: @MichaelDuffett Therefore, you need to evaluate the `line` for null in the `while()` loop since you are trying to call `line.equal()` when it is possible `line` to become null, causing the `NullPointerException`... https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/stop-returning-null-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you're calling is.read(bytes) repeatedly, while bytes can potentially read the whole file in one go. Therefore, calling it repeatedly has no reason to limit the number of bytes read to the actual length of the file. Therefore, it reads more than just the file sent, and it swallows the lines you sent after the file, thus breaking your protocol. On some machines for some small enough files, the file can actually be read in one go, thus not reading more bytes than expected and not breaking your protocol. But that's merely a chance encounter. You cannot rely on that.

You would need to instruct read() to not read more bytes than the number left to read to complete the file.

Not so obviously, you cannot wrap an InputStream or OutputStream from a socket, then re-use that same unwrapped InputStream or OutputStream. It will seem to work when you do that, until you run in corner cases when it doesn't run.

For instance, in client code, you're wrapping the InputStream in a BufferedReader to read lines, then at some point you're using the InputStream directly to read the bytes of the files. You can't do that. BufferedReader has lax rules about what constitutes and end of line, and will accept and consume the longest of either \r, \n, \f, or \r\n. If the server is running on a weird Mac-like system and its ends of lines are \r, but then you're sending a file of which the first byte happens to be \n, then the client will the \r from the end of line, then the \n from the file, and consider the sequence of both as the actual end of line. Thus you will have read and consumed the first byte of the file, which will corrupt its beginning, and which will make you read one additional byte at the end of the file and corrupt your protocol. Won't work.

Similar problems will always exist where you don't expect them if you use InputStream or OutputStream objects both in a wrapped and unwrapped form. You cannot do that and expect it will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now with using `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` for all communication, including sending the files.

Comment: That is indeed better suited.